# Angular-Google-Maps not showing marker on map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've read everything in the [Marker API guide](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api) of this angular directive, but I'm not able to show the marker on the map.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom="map.zoom" draggable="false" options="options">
    <ui-gmap-markers models="marker.id" coords="marker.coords" icon="marker.options.icon"></ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

and this is the controller which handles the map object:

angular.module('twoSpecials')
  .controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

```
$scope.map = {

    center: {
        latitude : 45.5674402,
        longitude: 12.4277687
    },
    zoom: 15        
}

$scope.options = {scrollwheel: false,
                  styles: [
                           {
                            "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                            "stylers": [
                              { "saturation": 100 },
                              { "weight": 0.1 },
                              { "hue": "#0077ff" },
                              { "color": "#f5f5dc" }
                            ]
                           }
                          ],
                  disableDefaultUI: true,
                 };

$scope.marker = {
    id : 0,
    coords : {
        latitude : 45.5674402,
        longitude: 12.4277687
    },
    options: {
        icon: 'images/marker.jpg'
    }

}
  });
```

Since I'm using Yeomann and I've build the Angular app with this tool, I've put the marker icon in the "images" folder that Yeomann creates. Do I have to put the images in another folder? Am I using this directive in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Your ui-gmap-marks icon attribute is incorrect. Try icon="marker.options.icon".

Comment: Not showing even in this case. Do you have any clue?

Comment: hmm can you provide a fiddle?